# Accessing items in listView row in onClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have an OnClickListener for my ListView.

I want to do these things in my onClickListener:
1- define an onClickListener for entire row not textboxes inside rows.
2- when a row clicked, I want to know which row is clicked?

this is what I've done to handle onClickListener on a Textbox:

```
private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String item = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(context, "SHIT Happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

and this is my getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_row, parent,false);
    TextView title =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);

    News temp = list.get(position);
    title.setText(temp.getTitle());
    date.setText(temp.getsDate());

    title.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return row;
}
```

this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newsRow"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width="210dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width="100dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtNewsID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:width="100dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think I should create an onClickListener for LinearLayout, but when I did that I didn't now how to access textbox value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instaed of writing `OnClickListener()`, you write `OnItemClickListener()` for your **listview**. For example :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos,
                          long arg3) {

        Log.v("position--", ""+pos); 
        //Here pos is the position of row clicked   

      }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})

Comment: where I should write this? To the activity which is using the custom adapter, or to the getView method in the custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to your ListView.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(YourOnItemClickListener);

Then in your listview xml attributes, set these properties-

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="false"
```

And your `R.layout.news_row`-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"       
     >


  //other views

</RelativeLayout>
```

These properties will pass events occured to a listview row to all child views inside `R.layout.news_row`.

For more information, I recommend reading [this](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/).